# Android Studio - Issues with using progress bar while AsyncTask loads website content

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am making a guessing app in Android Studio 2.2.3 for which I need to load some data from a website. I am using an AsyncTask class, which accepts the URL of the website as a String, and returns the data as String.

The problem is that the loading is extremely slow and so the app shows a blank white screen on the phone for about 15-20 seconds until (I presume) the whole thing is downloaded.

What I want to do is show an indeterminate progress bar (I think that's what the rotating circle is called) until the app loads the data.

For this, I tried to pass  in the AsyncTask, and then made the progressbar view visible in the onPreExecute() and invisible again in the onPostExecute().

But this didn't work out and it still showed the same white screen.

Here's my AsyncTask:

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

        try {

            url = new URL(urls[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isr.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char) data;

                result += current;

                data = isr.read();

            }

            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        //if try fails
        return null;
    }

}
```

And this is when I call it in the onCreate()

```
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    String result;

    try {

        String websiteUrl = "http://www.india-forums.com/celebrity/bollywood/";

        result = downloadTask.execute(websiteUrl).get();
```

I read somewhere that the get() blocks the main UI thread, but if I remove it, I get an Incompatible types error, so couldn't still resolve it...

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *What am I missing/doing wrong?* you are using `AsyncTask.get`...  Also off-topic comment: why you are reading stream byte by byte instead using buffer?

Comment: Sorry I am new to AsyncTask... What should I be using instead of AsyncTask.get?? Thanks!

Comment: Okay thanks, also what is the difference between using it byte by byte vs. buffer, it's ultimately the same data, right?

Comment: Obviously speed and memory usage ... You are adding char to string in every iteration.. It creates new String every time..

Comment: Would that use something like: BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in) ??